# How to mask the key displayed in API-Umbrella Key Signup

Tags: api-umbrella

We are using API-Umbrella static html pages and have customized the index.html with our org logo. We would like to email the API Key and not display it on the API Key Signup page (similar to data.gov). The static-web folder does not provide an handle to control the response we get back and protect the token. How do we not display the API Key in the User object in the response?

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameters `verifyEmail: true`, signupConfirmationMessage to
`/opt/api-umbrella/embedded/apps/static-site/releases/../build/signup/index.html`

```
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
var apiUmbrellaSignupOptions = {
    registrationSource: 'web',
    apiKey: 'xyz',
    verifyEmail: true,
    signupConfirmationMessage: 'Signup Confirmation'
};
```